# Chrome 39 crashes after a few minutes on XP

Tags: google-chrome

Over the weekend some of our PCs updated Chrome to v 39. Some PCs that are running XP are having problems. Chrome crashes every 2 or 3 minutes. It will open a new tab (by itself) and then an error is shown that says that a problem has occurred with Chrome and it needs to be closed. This happens even if the browser is opened but not used for anything.

Chrome's crash page shows 0 reports. Chrome beta 40 also fails.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Windows XP is no longer supported, expect more software to fail as upgrades come out. Just the tip of the iceberg as the world leaves Windows XP behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was SP3 missing, so update to SP3 and problem solved.